# Android material Chips, how to use them, which class is this?

Tags: android, tags, material-design, android-chips

I would like to display words in a way like a Tag Cloud looks. For this android material chips would be the perfect choice for me, but I can't find anywhere in the docs how to use them.

It is mentioned in the design guidelines only: 
https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/chips.html

Where could I find more info about it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now chipView is available only as third party library

you can use
https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

or
this
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/chips/

Comment: For **AndroidX** with autocomplete functionality https://github.com/karanatwal/MaterialChipsInput

Answer (score 1):

A built-in component does not exist. You have to create it yourself or use some library like this https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips